# What is the best way to disable horizontal scroll of UIScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling, contentsize

In `UIScrollView`, I have content height and width greater than scrollview's size. So basically it can scroll horizontally and vertically. What I want is to scroll vertically only and I manage horizontally scroll using an `UIButton` by using below code.

```
 [scrlViewQuestion setContentOffset:CGPointMake(questionWidth, 0) animated:YES];
```

Preventing horizontal scrollview, one can just set scrollview content width lesser than scrollview size but in my case scrollview content width is greater than its size? So what is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 8):

Content UIView width should be equal to the width of UIScrollView's superview for instance, not UIScrollView itself.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 5**
first, you should create a delegation class or extend the view control with `UIScrollViewDelegate`, and after, you should check the content offset with `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` func and disable it with that:
here is a sample code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    .
    .
    .
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self 
 }
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.x != 0 {
            scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this view hierarchy and these constraints

[image]

---

**Step by Step explanation of the image**

Place your ScrollView inside of a view(OuterView).

Place the view with your content(InnerView) inside the ScrollView

Align the ScrollViews 4 sides to the OuterViews 4 sides

```
ScrollView.leading = OuterView.leading
ScrollView.trailing = OuterView.trailing
ScrollView.top = OuterView.top
ScrollView.bottom = OuterView.bottom
```

Align the InnerViews 4 sides to the ScrollViews 4 sides

```
InnerView.leading = ScrollView.leading
InnerView.trailing = ScrollView.trailing
InnerView.top = ScrollView.top
InnerView.bottom = ScrollView.bottom
```

Set the InnerViews width and height equal to the **OuterViews width, *NOT* the ScrollViews width.**

```
InnerView.width = OuterView.width
```

[Source](https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `contentSize` of your scrollview to the width of your screen and the actual height of your scrollable content. Set the `contentInset` to zero for the `top`, `bottom`, and `right`. For the content inset on the `left` always choose the negated `x` coordinate of the position you currently want to display.

E.g. if your screen is 320 points wide, and you want to display content with horizontal scrolling fixed at `x`, but vertical scrolling allowed:

```
CGFloat screenWidth = 320.0;
CGSize actualContentSize = CGSizeMake(3000, 3000);

[scrlViewQuestion setContentSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth, actualContentSize.height)];
[scrlViewQuestion setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -x, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: More precisely, set `contentSize.width` to the width of the scroll view (e.g. `scrollView.bounds.size.width`). However, if you are using layout constraints, autolayout will reset the scroll view's `contentSize` when it runs (which is probably more often than you realize), so in that case, you need to modify your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

swift 4. set the delegate

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x != 0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

You can do this in storyboard.

[image]

Disable the `Show Horizontal Indicator` tab from the `Scroll View`'s Identity Inspector.It will disable your horizontal scrolling.

Comment: This only disables the scroll bars (UI) but does not stop the actual scrolling interaction